# CFB mode output is the same as CTR output; am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I've been trying to compare the encryption modes using AES and noticed that my CFB output is the same as my CTR output. Am I doing something wrong or is this supposed to happen? My CTR encryption function is identical to the CFB function below except with the "AES/CTR/NoPadding" string as the argument for Cipher.getInstance(). Thanks!

```
try {
        // Dernier exemple CTR mode
        // Clé 16 bits
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x83,
                (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xbd,
                (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x51,
                (byte) 0x5c, 0x73, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xf2};
        // IV 16 bits (préfixe du cipherText)
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xa8,
                (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xd4,
                (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x53,
                (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xec};

        // Initialisation
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Mode
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");

        String originalText = "hello i am original";
        // ///////////////////////////////ENCRYPTING
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        ciphered = cipher.doFinal(originalText.getBytes());
        String cipherText = new String(ciphered, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("ciphered: " + cipherText);
        // ///////////////////////////////DECRYPTING
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE , key, ivSpec);
        byte[] plain = cipher.doFinal(ciphered);
        originalText = new String(plain, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("plaintext: " + originalText);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: Try encrypting more than one block and see if they're still the same. They're basically the same if you're only encrypting a single block. You do have padding for CFB mode, which is a difference. And don't bother with `new String(ciphered, "UTF-8");`, it doesn't make any sense. You should probably hex-encode the output if you want to visualize it. Base64 is also an option.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That worked! Thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CFB (Cipher Feedback)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)) mode and [CTR (Counter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) mode are both [*modes of operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that specify how to use the basic block cipher primitive (AES in this case) to encrypt and decrypt byte sequences.

However, the very first block (16 bytes in this case) ends up being encrypted identically. Here is a diagram of CTR mode from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#/media/File:CTR_encryption_2.svg):
[image: CTR mode]

and here is a diagram of CFB mode, also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#/media/File:CFB_encryption.svg):

[image: CFB mode]

Focusing on the leftmost block you can see that they produce the same output in both case if the IV in CFB mode is the same as the Nonce/Counter in CTR mode.

Here is a slight modification of your code that shows the differences in encrypting `hello i am original` in the two modes.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Dernier exemple CTR mode
        // Clé 16 bits
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x83,
                (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xbd,
                (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x51,
                (byte) 0x5c, 0x73, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xf2};
        // IV 16 bits (préfixe du cipherText)
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xa8,
                (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xd4,
                (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x53,
                (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xec};

        // Initialisation
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Mode
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");

        String originalText = "hello i am original";
        // ///////////////////////////////ENCRYPTING
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] ciphered = cipher.doFinal(originalText.getBytes());
//            String cipherText = new String(ciphered, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("CFB: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(ciphered));

        // CTR mode
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        ciphered = cipher.doFinal(originalText.getBytes());
        System.out.println("CTR: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(ciphered));

    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
CFB: 25F64E6F324681A2B6534807BAFB11C52C0F9BBD28BE2032915EB423B1E0B415
CTR: 25F64E6F324681A2B6534807BAFB11C59390BE
```

CTR mode basically turns a block-cipher into a byte-oriented stream cipher, so the length of the ciphertext is the same as that of the plaintext. That also means that it's relatively easy for an attacker to modify the ciphertext to induce predictable changes in the decrypted plaintext. For this reason you must use a MAC to detect any modifications to the cipher, for example HMAC. The modern choice is AES-GCM, which is a counter-like mode that also includes a built-in MAC.

Comment: Why is the CTR output shorter than the CFB output?

Comment: @justan0therlurker: I'll add some information to the answer.